# how to properly resove package dependencies

Tags: package-management

I am trying to install the following packages:

```
apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib  postgresql-common libpq-dev
```

The message I get is:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: krb5-multidev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: comerr-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there a proper way to get these resolved without diving into a rabbit hole of hunting these dependencies one by one, in which case, I'm sure, each of them will have some other dependencies of their own

Comment: Use `aptitude` for interactive resolution. Otherwise you'll need to indicate on the command line which version of the conflicting package you want to install.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean ` and then try again..

Comment: this definitely helped me move further, thanks a lot!

Comment: please confirm that the above command solved the problem so that i can put it as the answer to the question..

Answer (score 0):

First do an update

apt-get update

Then install missing dependencies

apt-get install libssl-dev krb5-multidev comerr-dev

Hopefully the packages will be received. Otherwise, you will have to manually search for packages over internet and install.This happens mainly because the packages are not present in the configured repositories

Then install your packages.

apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib  postgresql-common libpq-dev